# Requesting data in PDO from up to 3 different tables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**What am I trying to do?**

I'm trying to display Invoices data on the Dashboard page of my web application. The tiny road block that I have came upon is displaying data based on integers. For example;

```
Invoice 1 -> Bill User 1
```

What I'm trying to achieve is having that integer for either a User or Company to whom the Invoice is assigned display their name, example;

```
BillContact->1 (becomes) BillContact->John Smith
```

Here is the current output of my data in PHP from PDO
[image]

If I was using old school MySQL I would write secondary query but I know this isn't much needed in PDO as you can just use UNION or JOIN, problem is I'm not very skilled with PDO or UNION/JOIN function, and would like to use this question as a way to learn how they work and use them in my code for future database queries.

As you can see Contact Billed are there assigned values, which I wish to replace with the Contact's name from Contacts table in the same Database.

Here is my PDO code to pull the current data.

```
$database->query('SELECT * FROM invoices LIMIT 10');
$rows = $database->resultset();

echo ... table html here

foreach($rows as $row)
                    {
                    ... td html here
                    }

echo ...
```

And here is the values I wish to pull from Contacts/Companies tables depending on id being passed.

```
contacts           companies
.firstname         .companyname       
.lastname
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know what you think PDO is but you can run standard SQL code through it... just like with any other database extension.

Comment: Could you add the schema of the contacts table?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález PDO -> PHP Data Objects. I know what it is, but I just happen to hate it, it was much easier using the old school SQL without crazy :foo in prepare instead of good old $foo

Comment: @Akshay sql scheme added

Comment: The legacy MySQL extension (if you mean that) was easier only if you used it wrong (opening your app to SQL injection). Whatever, what I mean is that the SQL syntax is exactly the same. PDO is not an ORM.

Comment: You can use "good old $foo" with PDO if you don't need your code to be injection safe.

Comment: No wonder you hate "PDO" because your "resultset" stuff is not PDO at all

Comment: @PaulSpiegel one reason why I moved to :foo, less need to write constant functions to validate form data being passed

Comment: @YourCommonSense kind of invalid statement.                                          public function resultset(){
    $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

Comment: Exactly. That's what I am talking about. It's *YOU* made your experience with PDO such a troublesome, so, don't blame PDO then.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I did not make my experience troublesome. I tried to look into it and learn it, and as much as I tried to learn it the more confused I became, until I dropped it and just referred to database abstraction with predefined Class hence resultset()

Comment: Well you see, it's all about logic. When used *properly*, PDO is *simpler* than old mysql_query stuff. If it's troublesome for you - blame not PDO but your own abstraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple join to solve your issue.

```
try
{
$s = $conn->prepare("SELECT inv.*,c.* from invoices inv, contacts c where inv.contact_billed = c.id");
$s->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: @YourCommonSense
Thank you for the link mate, I'd surely go through the entire article and increase knowledge :)